# Why does bash (from git installation) give me segmentation fault suddenly?

Tags: bash, git, segmentation-fault

I had a Git installation (version 2.16.2) on my Windows 10 Pro. And all of a sudden, it started throwing me segmentation fault when typing commands in bash.exe (all kinds of commands).

I uninstalled that version and installed the latest (2.18.0) but I still have the same issue.

I don't know what to do to get my bash back. I also use Cmder which has its own bash installation and it throws me the same error.

I don't know if it's of any use but here is the stackdump I got from executing ls in a bash terminal:

```
Stack trace:
Frame        Function    Args
000FFFF4F90  0018005E579 (00000000000, 7FFBD63D123C, 001800B4260, 000FFFFDE50)
00000000002  0018006056A (00000000064, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
000FFFF5270  00180125C3B (00000000000, 00600039ED9, 0000000526C, 00000400000)
000FFFF5C00  0018005E9AD (00180040000, FB1C005E1000, 000FFFF55F0, 000FFFF55B0)
000FFFF55F0  7FFBDAFD50BD (00000000000, FFFFFFFFFFFFFF00, 00000000002, 00000000012)
000FFFF55F0  7FFBDAF4D278 (0000000064C, 00180320820, 00000000000, 00000000000)
0000000064C  7FFBDAFD3FEE (000FFFF62D0, 00000000002, 000FFFF6480, 000FFFF64A0)
0000000064C  0018009DEE8 (00000000000, 000FFFF65D0, 0018006422C, 00000000000)
0000000001F  00180144850 (001800E1FA5, 00100425B20, 00000000002, 000003A0000)
001005FA650  0018011DE4B (001800E1FA5, 00100425B20, 00000000002, 000003A0000)
001005FA650  00100428EFB (00000000003, 00180320B08, 0018013835B, 0010000008B)
001005FA650  00100429B18 (000000019F0, 00000000000, 001005F57D8, 00000000000)
00000000001  00100432960 (00100000001, 006001BE820, 00100468FA0, 0010045B140)
006001BF830  00100437B9A (00000000076, 00000000077, 001800BBA9E, 000FFFF67FC)
006001BECF0  00100438BF4 (00000000001, 00100000000, 000FFFF691C, 00000000000)
006001BEF30  00100439A8C (00100000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
End of stack trace (more stack frames may be present)
```

EDIT:
Here are some examples of the commands I executed: git status, git commit, ls, pwd, ...

Comment: Try to do the same from docker container; Also add some information about your enviroment and command which you execute; Thanks!

Comment: I'll try in a docker container and let you know of the results. What information do you want about my environment?

Answer (score 0):

It started working again after a Windows update. Unfortunately I don't know what the problem was...