# Git Bash -Segmentation Fault Problem (Windows)

Tags: windows, git, segmentation-fault, git-bash

Indeed I have same issue which is mentioned here "[Why does bash (from git installation) give me segmentation fault suddenly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52151643/why-does-bash-from-git-installation-give-me-segmentation-fault-suddenly)
"

My git was working properly. But I need to regenerate keygen value and I got segmentation fault. I remoted git and installed the latest version of git (2.19.0-64-bit). I tried with git-bash from search, bash.exe from bin folder , git.exe from bin folder , git-bash.exe under Git Folder and git-cmd.exe under Git folder. The results are same.

After I read the link I shared above , I checked the windows updates as well. But there is no update.

Is there any idea ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2.9 is not the latest, one: 2.19 is.

Try (for testing) and uncompress the [latest Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) portable archive [`PortableGit-2.19.0-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.19.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.19.0-64-bit.7z.exe) anywhere you want.

Then setup a simplified path in a CMD session.

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
set GIT_HOME=C:\Path\to\Git
set PATH=%GIT_HOME%;%GIT_HOME%\bin;%GIT_HOME%\usr\bin;%GIT_HOME%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

(Add any other path you would need)

Try then to regenerate your SSH key.

Also, make sure this is not related to an AV (Anti-Virus) as in [issue 1832](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1832#issuecomment-421481865) or [issue 1291](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1291#issuecomment-421061157).

> My company also uses TrendMicro.
>   Can confirm that making an exception for `/Git/usr/bin/bash.exe` works as well.
>
> For me it was `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`, but adding it to the list of trusted programs did indeed fix the issue

Comment: The version is 2.19 I had an typo.Sorry my bad I edited.  And I solved the problem using PortableGit. I guess the problem was related mingw64\bin and usr\bin. IF Im not wrong they were not added into the PATH when I execute the installer. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem yesterday. Using git-bash, all my commands (i.e. mvn, javac, git pull) were giving error "Segmentation fault". This was because an update of my machine anti-virus which blocks proper access to my local login profile (sambit-swain@TERMINAL) After un-installing it, everything went back to normal.

So, the problem is not with GIT BASH or any other configuration. I should have checked the access levels (including SSH keys) to programs.